# Php and mysql display column names

Tags: mysql

I have table with the following fields

```
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | name | sports_1 | sports_2 | sports_3 |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+
|  3 | jack |        1 |        0 |        1 |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to only display that column names that contain 1. To have the following results.

```
Jack does sport_1 sports_3
```

Comment: Yes, I want to drive ten brand new sportcars at once (but that does not work). So what is your actual programming question? For more information on how to write a good question, please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se. Change the wording so that it's clear what you've done so far and what your concrete programming question is, where you hit the roadblock etc..

Comment: In addition to @hakre 's comment, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: With your current schema it can't be done.  But that's okay because the schema in question is wrong anyway. :)  You might want to look at a schema that makes better use of foreign keys, intersection tables, etc.

Comment: @GordonM: Of course it can be done; it's merely a matter of inspecting the record and constructing the output string appropriately (but now you've removed the [tag:PHP] tag, one would have to do it in SQL which is still possible but a bit more painful: `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name, 'does', IF(sport_1,'sport_1',NULL), IF(sport_2,'sport_2',NULL), IF(sport_3,'sport_3',NULL), IF(sport_1 OR sport_2 OR sport_3,NULL,'no sports')) FROM ...`).

Comment: @eggyal Okay, I'll amend my statement. Doing it in MySQL with the current schema is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just work around and you may change the structure of your table as chrisR said

but here if you want you can look this if it help you.

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
     if (!$con)
             {
              die('Could not connect ya rafik : ' . mysql_error());
              }
   mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable2 ORDER BY name ");

   // please use PDO or mysqli instead.
```

and then you manage results by php like this

```
   while ($column_data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query)) {
          echo $column_data['name']." does : ";
        if ($column_data['sports_1'] == 1 ){echo "  Sport1  ";} else {}
        if ($column_data['sports_2'] == 1 ){echo "  Sport2  ";} else {}
        if ($column_data['sports_3'] == 1 ){echo "  Sport3  " ;} else {}
           echo "<br />" ;

      }
```

the database is like that

```
id  name    sports_1    sports_2    sports_3
1   Mark      1               0         1
2   John      0               1         1
```

the the result will be like that:

```
    John does : Sport2  Sport3
    Mark does : Sport1  Sport3
```

Answer (score 7):

The thing you actually want is another table structure. I'll elaborate a little.

The thing you are describing is a many-to-many relationship. The sports you have in columns should actually be contained in another table called "sports" and in between the "users" table and the "sports" table you have a new table called "users_to_sports" connecting the two.

Check http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/ for a more in-depth explanation

Comment: I was going to write a query, but your solution is much better.